# Questions regarding the way rpm installation/upgrade takes place

Tags: linux, package-management, rpm

Below is the quote from my textbook while explaining naming convention of a package (eg : packagename-a.b.c-x.arch.rpm).

> **Build No** : The number following the version number (x) is the build
>   number. Many distribution maintainers add a letter code to the build
>   number to distinguish their packages from those of others. Note that
>   these numbers are not comparable across package maintainers— George's
>   build number 5 of a package is not necessarily an improvement on
>   Susan's build number 4 of the same package.

Below is the quote while explaining upgrading of a package

> **Warning**: It's possible to distribute the same program under different
>   names. In this situation, upgrading may fail or it may produce a
>   duplicate installation, which can yield bizarre program-specific
>   malfunctions. Red Hat has described a formal system for package naming
>   to avoid such problems, but they still occur occasionally. Therefore,
>   it's best to upgrade a package using a subsequent release provided by
>   the same individual or organization that provided the original.

**Q-1** So as per quote-1; the build no. is associated with some letter specific to distro. maintainer, so it may fail to upgrade because of different name? & thus wont know whether its an upgraded version over current installation?

**Q-2** But in case of same distro/name how does rpm decide whether its an upgraded version ? Does it parse the name of the package and pick the version-no from the name? If yes then why would it fail in case of different distro. as well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build number is called a release. For example for `python-qt5-5.10-3.fc28.x86_64`, the name is "python-qt5" the version is "5.10" and the release is "3.fc28" and the last one is an architecture "x86_64"

What you call as George's or Susan's letter is usually called as a "dist tag". In the example above it is ".fc28". It is used to distinguish between different packages of the same version and release. For example python-qt5 for Fedora 28 puts files into `/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages`, but this will not work on RHEL6 as it expects python modules in `/usr/lib64/python2.6` directory. So RHEL6 version of the same package is `python-qt5-5.10-3.el6.x86_64`

RPM itself compare just the name, version and release. There is no logic that you cannot install Fedora 28 package on RHEL7. It usually does not work, because of other dependencies. For example if you try upgrade your `python-qt5-5.10-3.fc28.x86_64` with `python-qt5-5.10-4.el7.x86_64` it will likely not work because of different SONAMEs of libQT*.so on RHEL7. But if you do that with some package, which does not have any requirements (or very relaxed requirements), then rpm itself will allow the upgrade because "4.el7" is bigger than "3.fc28". The problem is that author of the rpm package does not intend (nor tested) to install his package on a different platform. Rarely it does work but mostly does not.

Comment: So there is no meta information inside the package used by rpm to do installation or upgrade ? its just the name of the package file through which it decides whether its an upgraded version then the currently installed software ?

Comment: `but this will not work on RHEL6 as it expects python modules in /usr/lib64/python2.6 directorya` why does red hat expect it to be in that specific directory ?

Comment: Yes. RPM only compare NEVRA (name, epoch, version, release, architecture) to do the upgrade. If you are precise then Provides and Obsoletes play some role too, but it is just small technical detail.

Comment: Because RHEL6 have python 2.6 which expect this path. RHEL7 and Fedora has python 2.7.

Comment: `RPM only compare NEVRA (name, epoch, version, release, architecture) to do the upgrade.` But i can name the package whatever i like. In that case how does rpm figure out the upgrade. ?

Comment: I believe there got to be some file inside the package which might be storing NEVRA information.